# Name and Implementation for MD5 hashing password and salt before hashing them together

Tags: passwords, md5, salt, opendj

Is there a name for this variation of a salted MD5?
    $hash = md5( md5( $salt ) . md5( $password ) );
(for clarity the '.' there is concatenation)
And more importantly, can anyone find an implementation for this scheme for OpenDJ?

Comment: Only want to note, that this is an unsafe way to store passwords. MD5 is ways too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily. Todays password [cracker tools](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#features-algos) even implement a lot of variations of such schemes. Use a slow hash function with a cost factor instead (BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2).

Comment: I'm migrating these passwords. It really wasn't up to me how they were stored. New passwords will use a more secure algorithm, but these old ones will have to work just the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implementation of this scheme that I know of for OpenDJ. 
But password storage schemes in OpenDJ can be easily extended by implementing an extension of the PasswordStorageScheme abstract class.
I guess this is for migrating existing hashed passwords. Which product uses such algorithm ?

Comment: Invision Power Boards uses this scheme, and yes I need to migrate the passwords. https://www.invisionpower.com/support/guides/_/advanced-and-developers/miscellaneous/passwords-in-ipboard-r130
If you know of a good reference for extending PasswordStorageScheme, I would like it. Bottom line I would probably use the existing SMD5 scheme and add more hashing into it.

Comment: I think the best reference is to look at OpenDJ source code and password storage schemes that are in the extensions/ folder. The interface is pretty simple and starting from the MD5 one will make it easier.

Comment: I guess my problem is I don't know how to go about recompiling the entire thing.